# How would I disallow numbers as input?

Tags: python

Alright, so I defined a function where the user can input his/her name. I want to make it so that the user is not allowed to input a number like "69" for his/her name. How would I go about doing this? Here is the code I used:

```
def name():
    while True:
        name = input("What is your name? "))
        try:
            return str(name)
            break
        except TypeError:
            print("Make sure to enter your actual name.")
```

Comment: You have an extra parentheses on `input("What is your name? "))`

Comment: What about `"100Adam13"`, is that valid?

Comment: Also, this might be relevant: [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/) (Say, point 15.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [isalpha()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalpha) to check name:

> Return true if all characters in the string are alphabetic and there
>   is at least one character, false otherwise.

```
>>> "69".isalpha()
False
>>> "test".isalpha()
True
```

Here's your code with modifications:

```
while True:
    name = input("What is your name? ")
    if name.isalpha():
        break
    else:
        print("Make sure to enter your actual name.")
        continue
```

Or:

```
name = input("What is your name? ")

while not name.isalpha():
    print("Make sure to enter your actual name.")
    name = input("What is your name? ")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`str.isdigit()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit) method to check if the string contains just digits:

```
name = input("What is your name? ")

while name.isdigit():
    print("Make sure to enter your actual name.")
    name = input("What is your name? ")
```

Note that this will allow names like - `"Rohit1234"`. If you just want to allow alphabetic characters, then you can use [`str.isalpha()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalpha) method instead.

Comment: The only thing you forgot to put in was `return name`.

Comment: @Suds2. Of course. But I didn't even wrote a function there. I just gave an idea about the while loop. :)

Comment: @Suds2. So, you can adjust your function to add that loop, and return the `name` as required. And you're welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

Invert your logic:

```
while True:
    name = ...
    try:
       int(name)
       print "Name can't be a number."
    except TypeError:
       return str(name)
```

Mind you, this will accept any input that is not a valid integer, including `123abc` or so.